# How to measure memory bandwidth currently being used on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, memory

I'm writing a small Linux application which logs the computer's power consumption along with CPU utilisation and disk utilisation.  I'd like to add the ability to log memory bandwidth currently being used so I can see how well that correlates with a power consumption.

I understand that I can get information about the amount of memory currently *allocated* from `/proc/meminfo` but, of course, that doesn't tell me how much *bandwidth* is being used at present.  Does anyone know how I could measure memory bandwidth currently in use?

**edit**
I'd like this to work primarily on the x86 and x86-64 platforms

Comment: What "memory bandwidth" ? That as such is a constant quantity of the system, but even so there's a difference between L1 / L2 / L3 cache bandwidth, memory bandwidth for memory attached to the local CPU, attached to a "remote" CPU (if using a HT / QPI system), memory bandwidth for e.g. memory residing on the graphics card. Things like cache hit rates, cache fill/spill, CPU pipeline stalls due to memory waits etc. are quite probably a better measure / a better indicator of things amiss than a "glossy single figure".

Comment: @Frank: All excellent questions.  The short answer is: I'd love to measure and log all the metrics you mention  L1 & L2 & L3 & main memory utilisation).  My ultimate aim with this app is to be able to accurately predict power consumption without empirically measuring power consumption; instead I want to predict power consumption given only performance metrics like CPU utilisation, disk utilisation and memory utilisation.  Perhaps I should've said "memory _utilisation_" instead of "memory _bandwidth_".

Comment: On those, indeed they're very CPU-dependent; On Solaris/SPARC, there are utilities like `busstat`, `cputrack` or `trapstat` to give you many of these figures, but those have never been ported to x86 (nor would they, due to hardware architecture dependency). For Linux, http://lwn.net/Articles/312720/ gives a starting point for how to interact with the performance monitoring counters; the perf project wiki site is https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page which also gives examples.

Answer (score 8):

It's highly CPU-dependent but you'll need to be able to get access to the CPU's performance registers. You may be able to do this via oprofile. Note that not all CPUs have a performance register (or combination of registers) which can be used to calculate to memory bandwidth usage, however.

Comment: Many thanks for the very swift reply!  Can I get access to the performance registers directly from user space?  I assume not.  (BTW, in terms of CPU-dependent operations: I'm happy to specifically target relatively modern x86-64 processors like the Intel i5)

Comment: No - see http://anton.ozlabs.org/blog/2009/09/04/using-performance-counters-for-linux/

Comment: To add some more resources, cpu performance registers can be accessed through tools such as intel vtune (https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/) , and linux perf (https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)